# I am trying to scrape info from a website(Program name and program ID and location) using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** info from a website(Program name and program ID) and it is returning empty list.
I am not sure if i am mixing up the syntax but this is what i have
soup.find_all('h3', class_='ama__h3')

the website link is https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/#/programs?program=residencies&specialtiesToSearch=140

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlsplit
import requests

res = requests.get('https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/#/programs?program=residencies&specialtiesToSearch=140')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')

print(soup.prettify())

soup.find_all('h3', class_='ama__h3')
```

Comment: if your question is answered, do not hesitate to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you are parsing with html5lib. For any well formed html, the parser choice is not really important. However for a non well formed html (like this one), html5lib seems to have issues. You should use `html.parser` or `lxml` (apparently `html.parser` is safer)

However this code is doing what you want to do :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

programs = soup.find_all("a", class_='ama__promo--background')
for program in programs:
    program_name = program.find("h3").text
    program_id = program.find_all("small")[-1].text.split(': ')[1].strip()
    print(program_name, program_id
```